# different color and labels by iPhone 11 and 11 Pro but same App

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, label, viewcontroller

im testing my App right now. all is good and I have no errors.

today I tested the app on the iPhone from my Girlfriend(iPhone 11) and all looks good.
than I tested my app on my iPhone (iPhone 11Pro)and I have some problems.

the biggest on is a Text Label. white background and a black text, by my Girls Phone all good.
but on my Phone I see no Text. the label and Button is working but I see no label.

the next problem some text is black by my girl (that's right) and by me is the text label White.

tell me if you need some Pictures.

hope you can help me and thank you for your time.
[View iPhone 11 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPsBa.jpg)

[View iPhone 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyFzp.png)

Comment: Sounds like an issue with dark mode / light mode

Comment: hm no cuz I do nothing like this right now I only work with buttons, labels, and view controllers and not much code xD

Comment: iOS will automatically change various system UI elements when the interface style changes. You either need to set explicit colours so it does not do that, turn off dark mode globally for your app, or implement dark mode properly. Implementing it is usually not as difficult as it may seem and it makes for a much better user experience

Comment: You should generally not set elements to `.white` or `.black` as this won't work correctly when the light/dark mode changes. You should use `.labelColor` and `.systemBackgroundColor`.  This applies to both code and setting colors in a storyboard scene

Comment: ahh okay i chance in my phone settings from dark to light mode and I see all labels. now I have to look how I use dark and light mode in my app. thank you so much for your help !!!